# Neural Network cannot learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, neural-network, softmax

I am trying to implement a neural network with python and numpy. The problem is when I try to train my network the error stocks around 0.5. It cannot learn further. I tried learning rates 0.001 and 1. I guess I am doing something wrong during the back propagation. But I haven't been figured what is wrong.

p.s. I was getting a lot of overflow problems then I started to use np.clip() method.

Here is my back propagation code:

```
# z2 is softmax output
def calculateBackpropagation(self, z1, z2, y):
    delta3 = z2
    delta3[range(self.numOfSamples), y] -= 1
    dW2 = (np.transpose(z1)).dot(delta3)
    db2 = np.sum(delta3, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    delta2 = delta3.dot(np.transpose(self.W2)) * ActivationFunction.DRELU(z1)
    dW1 = np.dot(np.transpose(self.train_data), delta2)
    db1 = np.sum(delta2, axis=0)

    self.W1 += -self.alpha * dW1
    self.b1 += -self.alpha * db1
    self.W2 += -self.alpha * dW2
    self.b2 += -self.alpha * db2

# RELU can be approximated with soft max function
# so the derivative of this function is g(x) = log(1+exp(x))
# Source: https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/rectifier-nonlinearities/
@staticmethod
def DRELU(x):
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    return np.log(1 + np.exp(x))

def softmax(self, x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    e = np.exp(x)
    return e / np.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)

def train(self):
    X = self.train_data
    Y = self.train_labels
    (row, col) = np.shape(self.train_data)
    for i in xrange(self.ephocs):
        [p1, z1, p2, z2] = self.feedForward(X)
        probs = z2
        self.backPropagate(X, Y, z1, probs)

        self.learning_rate = self.learning_rate * (self.learning_rate / (self.learning_rate + (self.learning_rate * self.rate_decay)))

def softmax(self, x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    e = np.exp(x)
    return e / np.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)
def feedForward(self, X):

    p1 = X.dot(self.W1) + self.b1
    z1 = self.neuron(p1)
    p2 = z1.dot(self.W2) + self.b2
    # z2 = self.neuron(p2)
    z2 = self.softmax(p2)
    return [p1, z1, p2, z2]

def predict(self, X):
    [p1, z1, p2, z2] = self.feedForward(X)
    return np.argmax(z2, axis=1)

# Calculates the cross-entropy loss
# P.S. In some cases true distribution is unknown so cross-entropy cannot be directly calculated.
# hence, I will use the cross entropy estimation formula on wikipedia
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy
def calculateLoss(self, x):
    [p1, z1, p2, z2] = self.feedForward(x)
    softmax_probs = self.softmax(p2)
    # Calculates the estimated loss based on wiki
    return np.sum(-np.log(softmax_probs[range(self.numOfSamples), self.train_labels]))

def neuron(self, p):
    return ActivationFunction.RELU(p)

def CreateRandomW(self, row, col):
    return np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(row, col))

def normalizeData(self, rawpoints, high=255.0, low=0.0):
    return (rawpoints/128.0) - 1

@staticmethod
def RELU(x):
    # x = np.clip( x, -1, 1 )
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    return np.maximum(0.001, x)

# RELU can be approximated with soft max function
# so the derivative of this function is g(x) = log(1+exp(x))
# Source: https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/rectifier-nonlinearities/
@staticmethod
def DRELU(x):
    x = np.clip( x, -500, 500 )
    return np.log(1 + np.exp(x))
```

Comment: Is the objective function decreasing?

Comment: No it does not. I can't minimize the cross entropy error. It is always around the same

Comment: You might want to simplify the activation function to the identity as long as its not decreasing

Comment: My activation function is RELU. How can I simplify it? (I use max(0, x))

Comment: You can set the activation to the identity f(x)=x. I'm suggesting this since I assume the gradients are computed incorrectly (the update rule seems okay), but you could also test your code on a toy dataset, and verify the objective is calculated correctly.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you change the gradients accordingly? which paper are you looking at for the equations?

Comment: I was looking the gradient from https://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/rectifier-nonlinearities/

Comment: Also, I realized that after I call backPropagation softmax probs(z2) becomes all -0.5

Comment: The SoftMax outputs should be non-negative, and your impl' seems correct...
If you share your training code I can try to figure it out (no need for the data).

Comment: I edited the post with train code.

Comment: Here is also link https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzhenLaF0FKGMFRfb1R1NlR4T00&usp=sharing

Comment: I fixed one bug. The neuron() function calls RELU(Sigmoid(x)) for some reasons, instead of just RELU(x)
The code is still not working though, the training accuracy does not go above 0.6. I'll look for another bug later.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues I found:

1. The array slicing softmax_probs[r, y] in calculateLoss() is incorrect. This slicing produces a 10000x10000 matrix and slows down the code.
2. Similarly, the slicing of delta3[r, y] in backPropagate() is incorrect.
3. As of yet, I'm unsure if backprop is done correctly (didn't check), however, clipping the gradients to (-5, 5), I was able to get just below 70% training and testing accuracy after 100 iterations,

I used the output of the following utility function (one-to-K encoding of the labels) to fix both issues 1 and 2.

```
def one_to_two_encoding(y):
    v = np.array([[1, 0] if y[i] == 0 else [0, 1] for i in range(len(y))])
    return v
```

I applied gradient clipping in backPropagte() right after each gradient is computed. For example,

```
delta3 = delta3.clip(-5, 5)
```

Comment: Using RELU and increasing to 400 iterations I got 76%/75% training/testing accuracy. Hidden units = 30, Learning rate=0.01, decay = 0.98, where I set learning_rate *= decay after each iteration.